# Angular2 - should RC6 compile to ES5 or ES6?

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I have just upgraded to RC6 and I am getting compile errors for **my code** related to find.  Here is an example.

> TS2339: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'string[]'.

I also get file compile errors in the **angular code** under node_module s(why does it try to compile this?).  Here are a few:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
>
> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

I can solve this by setting the tsConfig target to es6 but the angular2 quickstart still shows ES5.  I don't want to deviate too far from that at this point.

I am using typescript 2.0.0.